# how i can access to other sql server at local network with my site?

Tags: sql-server, iis, connection

i design a web site in local network with visual studio.
i use sql server in my site and when use it in current computer run success but when i try connect to other sql server in other computer in local network get this error:

> SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

when i run with iis express in visual studio all is true but in iis get error
i change many item in iis manager but cant correct this problem

> notice:

i can connect with this setting in visual studio by press F5 . when i go from address that set with IIS , i get this Error
i use sql2000 in local network

Comment: You realise SQL Server 2000 was released 23 years ago, i'm not even going to bother with how out of date and unsupported it is, it's about time you got up to date; no one is going to be able to assist on 23yr old software, not to mention this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open TCP/IP protocal and open the sql port. You can reference [how i can access to other sql server at local network with my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76513356/how-i-can-access-to-other-sql-server-at-local-network-with-my-site).
Besides,the connection string is like `UseSqlServer("Data Source=192.168.2.68;Initial Catalog=UserAuth;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx;TrustServerCertificate=True")` .

Comment: i can connect with this setting in visual studio by press F5 . when i  go from address that set with IIS , i get this Error

Comment: By the way, my SQL is 2000

Answer (score 0):

Check the TCP/IP parameter in the SQL Server Configuration Manager
[image]

Comment: Yes i checked it :(  notice: every things is true when i run in visual studio But my problem are when accessing from ip address (in IIS)